# How to find intersect in dataframe between all the columns in R?

Tags: r, statistics

```
for (i in 1:length(df)) {
  save = list()
  save[[i]] = Reduce(intersect, list(df[i],(df[i]+1)))
}
```

I have a dataframe df with 1000 samples with each sample being a column. I need to find the intersection between these 1000 sets. I have trouble writing loops so not sure how to do this.

Comment: Could you please provide a minimal data set - probably only needs three columns with 10 rows each showing your expected output. Please paste the data into the question using `dput(your_data0` See [MRE] for guidance on asking questions.

Comment: `Reduce(intersect, df)` alone should do it. Or do you want the pairwise intersections?

Comment: I think its pairwise from the likes of the question.

Answer (score 0):

intersection between 2 samples combination (pairwise)

```
sapply(l, function(x) sapply(patient_aa, function(y) intersect(x,y)))
```

intersection among all samples

```
Reduce(intersect, l)
```